# Disable stemming for a exact phrase match

Tags: elasticsearch

I have stemming enabled on my analyzer with a standard tokenizer. How can I disable stemming for extact phrase matches?

For example, I have the following query:

```
                "query_string" : {
                    "fields" : ["*content],
                    "default_operator": "AND", 
                    "query" :"\"TRANSIENT ISCHAEMIC ATTACK\"",
                    "use_dis_max" : true,
                    "phrase_slop": 0
                }
```

The problem currently is that it returns `TRANSIENT ISCHAEMIC ATTACKS` and `TRANSIENT ISCHAEMIC ATTACK`, I only want it to return `TRANSIENT ISCHAEMIC ATTACK` but I still want to retain the ability to search for root words for non exact phrase queries.